# SQL query - Count different values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have this table:

| textid | sentiment | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | negative | 2020-01-02 |
| 2 | positive | 2020-01-02 |
| 3 | neutral | 2020-01-02 |
| 4 | negative | 2020-01-02 |
| 5 | negative | 2021-08-10 |
| 6 | positive | 2018-10-22 |
| 7 | negative | 2021-03-10 |
| 8 | neutral | 2019-11-30 |
| 9 | negative | 2019-12-29 |

And I want to count the different values of `sentiment`over time... to later build a graph where I can compare the variation of three sentiments over date.

So, give the example table... I need a table like this:

| date | countPositive | countNeutral | countNegative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2018-10-22 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2019-11-30 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2019-12-29 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2020-02-01 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-03-10 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2021-08-01 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Anyone can help me? I don't know how to perform this SQL query...

Thanks!

Comment: Use case expressions to do conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation, which in Postgres means `filter`:

```
select date,
       count(*) filter (where sentiment = 'positive') as positive,
       count(*) filter (where sentiment = 'neutral') as neutral,
       count(*) filter (where sentiment = 'negative') as negative
from t
group by date;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by date and filter count() :

```
select
 date 
, count(*) filter (where sentiment  = 'positive') countPositive
 , count(*) filter (where sentiment  = 'neutral') countNeutral
 , count(*) filter (where sentiment  = 'negative') countNegative
from yourtable
group by date
```

if the date column is actually date/time , you need to cast it to date first:

```
select
 date_trunc('day', now()) 
 , count(*) filter (where sentiment  = 'positive') countPositive
 , count(*) filter (where sentiment  = 'neutral') countNeutral
 , count(*) filter (where sentiment  = 'negative') countNegative
from yourtable
group by date_trunc('day', now())
```